# PHP order SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, arrays, xml, object, simplexml

I have an SimpleXMLElement Object:

```
 SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [@attributes] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1234 
        [color] => red 
    ) 
    [one] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [@attributes] => Array ( 
            [position] => 2 
            [close] => false 
        ) 
    ) 
    [two] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [@attributes] => Array ( 
            [position] => 0 
            [close] => false 
        ) 
    ) 
    [three] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [@attributes] => Array ( 
            [position] => 0 
            [close] => true 
        ) 
    )
)
```

Now I want to sort the Childs ("one", "two" "three") by the attribute "position".
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have a look here. You are going to have to use `array_multisort` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Answer (score -1):

Use this function:

```
function sortByKeyValue($the_array, $key)
{
   $cmp_val="((\$a['$key']>\$b['$key']) ? 1 : ((\$a['$key']==\$b['$key']) 0:-1))";
   $cmp=create_function('$a, $b', "return $cmp_val;");
   uasort($the_array, $cmp);

   return $the_array;
}
```

To use it do this:

```
sortByKeyValue(SimpleXMLElementObject, 'position')
```